# Entity Framework 4 + SQL Server CE + Generate database from model

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

The title sums up my problem. I start from an empty model in VS2010 beta2, and then choose to generate my database from model, i then choose to create a new SQL CE database. Up until that moment everything runs fine. EF generates some SQL and saves it as MyModel.emdx.sql. Here comes the problem, the generated SQL can't be executed on the CE database and throws a couple error messages, like 'ALTER TABLE is not supported' and some others.
I reckon there is no way to do Model first with an SQL CE database, so I'm back to the Database first approach. Or has anyone managed to sucessfully generate an SQL CE database from the edmx model in VS2010?

Comment: Could you generate a regular SQL Server DB and then port that to CE somehow?

Comment: I'm not really sure that would be easier than just going the database first route. I could also try and edit the generated SQL, or just recreate the database structure in CE per hand, which is not ideal, but since the database has only 3 tables, would be faster.

Comment: hey Gio2k! Have u had any success with this? Similar issue my side, except that I'm using VS2008 Pro

Answer (score 0):

I just ran a MyModel.edmx.sql script against an SQL CE database and it executed without error. I used VS 2010 RC, so I suspect the problem you encountered was related to the Beta 2 release. I conclude that the problem was fixed in the RC

Answer (score 0):

When you first **Generate Database from Model...**, you will create a connection in **App.Config**. If you initially created a non-CE connection, you will generate non-CE SQL, and it will get a .sql extension as you described (if your connection is to CE, you will get a .sqlce extension on the DDL file).

You need to delete the connectionstring from **App.Config**, and maybe the datasource from **Project -> Properties -> DataSources**. Then when you choose **Generate Database from Model...** it will ask to create a new connection, and you can choose a CE connection instead of a server one.